# Факторизация целых чисел

Tags: java, факторизация

У меня возник следующий вопрос: у меня есть код для факторизации числа, который работает. Однако в задание указано, что число должно вводится как "command line parameter". То есть в косноль должно вводится:

javac Factorization

java Factorization "число"

А затем ответ должен выходить в форме: число=множитель^степень*множитель^степень...
Я перерыл все что мог, но не нашёл как это сделать.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Primfaktorenzerlegung {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Geben Sie die Zahl ein");
  int num = scn.nextInt();
  String[] Primzahlen = new String[0];
  for(int i = 2; i<num; i++){
      while(num%i==0){
          System.out.println(i);
          num = num / i;
      }
  }
  if(num>2){
      System.out.println(num);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: по запросу `Факторизация целых чисел` первая же ссылка [how to factor a number java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223477/how-to-factor-a-number-java) ведёт на страницу с 7 различными вариантами ответа

Comment: Не совсем, там у них вывод в форме [x,x,x,y,y,y]. Мне необходима форма [x^n*y^m]. А так как я новичок еще, то не могу понять как сделать вывод именно такой. К тому же, в моем случае я не нашёл как сделать ввод числа в консоли, чтобы при вводе "java Primzahlenzerlegung *число*" сразу выводило ответ, а не просило заново ввести число

Comment: следующий запрос -> How to format strings in Java)... там выводиться массив, его можно преобразовать в строку

Comment: попробуй вместо nextInt() Integer.parseInt  [Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()) vs scanner.nextInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586489/integer-parseintscanner-nextline-vs-scanner-nextint)

Comment: Не нашёл как сделать что именно?

Comment: Как сделать чтобы при вводе команды java Primfaktorenzerlegung 500 мне выдавало 500 = 2^2 * 5^3

Answer (score 0):

Так суть вопроса в том как принять аргумент с консоли?
Все просто, `java Factorization "число"` - "число" это аргумент.
`public static void main(String args[])`
Все аргументы  попадают в массив args . Чтоб получить первый  аргумент - args[0] . Если это число `Integer.parseInt(args[0])`. Насчёт вывода , в комментариях дали ссылку на алгоритм, там по итогу получается коллекция. Посчитай количество совпадений числа это и будет степень и подставь в строку  . Посчитать можно через stream  filter count. Сначала избався от дубликатов через distinct чтоб понимать сколько разных чисел для которых искать повторения будешь. Всю нужную инфу тебе дали. Если тебе сейчас возьмут и готовый код дадут , тебе же хуже будет. Лучше потрать время , нагугли,  что тебе не понятно из того , что тут дали и ты в 100 раз больше профита получишь. Конечную строку кст можешь через цикл склеивать в зависимости от количества уникальных цифр в колекции , еще одна подсказка